# Realizar POST com Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Tenho uma String que preciso passar por parâmetro. Porém a variável concatenada é interpreta como um novo parâmetro e não valor. Há uma forma de passar String por parâmetro com este carácter ( & ) ?

Agradeço desde já.

```
var codhtml = '&teste = 5';

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'salvarDados.php',
    data: 'codhtml=' + codhtml + '&motivoid=2' + '&formatoid=2' + '&motivonome=Nome',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(txt) {
        alert("Sucesso,");
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Erro ao Salvar");
```

Comment: Qual é o HTML que estás a usar? Talvez dê para fazer simplesmente `$('form').serialize();` e ele faz isso por ti... Explica melhor a pergunta e vais ter respostas mais acertadas.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se funciona assim.

```
        var formatoid= '2';
        var motivoid = '2';
        var motivonome = 'Nome';
        var teste = '5';
$.ajax({

            url: 'salvarDados.php',
            data: {teste:teste, motivoid :motivoid, formatoid: formatoid ,motivonome : motivonome },
            method: 'POST',
            success : function(txt){
                 alert("Sucesso,");
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Erro ao Salvar");
```

Tenta usar teu $.ajax({}) assim, talvez funcione, eu apenas coloquei na ordem o vai executar e os exemplos de string que tu colocou.